# Unable to reinstall Windows 7 after dual-boot partition changes

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

Some time ago I had installed on my PC Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 and used to dual-boot them. After a while though I had to reinstall Windows 7. After that the boot only showed the Windows options, so I kinda forgot about the Ubuntu install.

A few days ago, I decided that I want Ubuntu back. I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 and tried to install it, but I couldn't get my way around on getting it on the boot menu (still the Windows boot manager was showing).

After many tries and fails nothing really changed.

A few hours ago I added EasyBCD to my Windows 7 and deleted one of the entries (had Windows 7 and Windows 7 loader), I deleted the Windows 7 Entry.

After that, when booting into windows it gives me a BSOD at the logo part (the 4 lights). So I decided to boot Ubuntu 13.10 from the USB to see what can be done.

Also when trying to reinstall Windows 7 it finds no drives (like disk partitions where to install it). Trying to do a system restore also doesn't work since it sees no Windows installations.

I tried using the cmd prompt from the installation disk and when I wrote: list volumes it only showed me the USB flash drives.

When trying to install Ubuntu, I can't make new partitions and I'm not sure how to go around changing the old ones (the only old partition I can edit is the one that has the files I need the most).

Problem is, now I have absolutely no clue how to install Ubuntu or fix my Windows. I would like to know the answers to both of this questions if possible.

***Diagnostic information***

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -lu 

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6d4b81ae

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        2048      206847      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          206848   256206847   128000000   42  SFS
/dev/sda4       256206848   842144347   292968750   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 3995 MB, 3995074560 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 485 cylinders, total 7802880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *         128     7802879     3901376    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            3.9G   56M  3.8G   2% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           789M  1.2M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sdc1       3.8G  883M  2.9G  24% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      843M  843M     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G  984K  3.9G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G   76K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Also, the windows 7 BSOD error is : 0x0000007B ( also known as 0x7b )

As far as I remember my partitions look like :

```
sda1 - 1MB I have no clue what this is but I guess it is due to EasyBCD or something 
sda2 - 104 MB - the one Windows always makes
sda3 - 131072MB - Classic C drive ( the place where Windows is installed ) 
sda4 - D: drive, where I keep my files.
```

Also on Windows I recall making 2 more partitions, one 30GB and one 8GB partition in order to install ubuntu on one of them and use the other as a swap point.

Some more information on this picture, as you can see the partitions don't look like they really are in GParted. (Click to magnify.)

[image: partitions]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution, but *part* of your problem is that when you added your two new partitions, Windows converted your disk from using standard partitions to using a Windows-specific [Logical Disk Manager (LDM, aka "dynamic disks")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) configuration. That's what the "SFS" partitions are in your `fdisk` output. Basically, Linux can't install to a disk that uses LDM, so you can rule out installing Linux to this disk unless and until you convert back from LDM to a standard partitioning scheme. There are proprietary Windows tools that can do this, such as [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) and one or two others. (I've never used these tools, though; I'm just reporting what I've heard about them.) Unfortunately, since you say you're having problems *in Windows,* my suspicion is that your LDM data have become damaged. A third-party tool might therefore become confused and fail to work, or even make matters worse. OTOH, perhaps a third-party tool would be able to fix the damage.

Overall, I'd say that your first step should be to perform a low-level backup of the disk. In Linux, I'd use `dd` for this, as in `dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/big/empty/space/sda.img`. This will store an image backup of `/dev/sda` in `/path/to/big/empty/space/sda.img`, so that if whatever you do to recover your data makes matters worse, you'll be able to restore it. Obviously, `/path/to/big/empty/space/sda.img` must be on a disk other than `/dev/sda`. There are Windows tools that will do the same thing, but I'm not very familiar with them, so I can't make any specific recommendations.

After that, there are at least two things you might try:

- Try running any recovery tool you think might help. You say you've tried standard Windows tools, but there may be such a tool that you've overlooked. There are also third-party tools that might do the job.
- Try deleting all your partitions using Linux `fdisk` or something similar and then running a filesystem-recovery tool like [TestDisk.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) This operation is risky because LDM can create discontiguous filesystems that won't be handled properly by TestDisk; but if it works, you might get back your filesystems, and in a form that Linux could then handle.

I make no guarantee that either approach will make your system bootable again. You might need to run Windows recovery tools to make that the case; or you might need to back up your personal data and re-install Windows.

Good luck!

Comment: Thnx for the answer, your the first and only one :). As for re-installing windows, I can't. The installer sees no drivers and no ex-installtion of windows. The only thing i can think of is installing ubuntu by wiping out the entire hard drive, then install windows by wiping it out again and then install ubnutnu again to dual-boot , anyway it would still be a requirement to save my personal data...

Comment: Windows doesn't need to see existing *partitions* to install, although it does need to see the *hard disk.* If Windows sees the disk but not the partitions, though, it will wipe out your data upon re-install, so recovering your personal data in one way or another should be a priority. If necessary, you can use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar (I gather there are Windows-only tools that are better for NTFS) to recover personal files, but that's likely to be tedious.